# When Injecting Javascript into a UIWebView from Settings I only get numbers?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uitextfield, settings

OK here goes,

This one i find complicated to explain, but I have attached the project if you want to test it out what I am trying to say:-)

I have 1 app - 2 views.
1 UIWebView with a local html file with a form
1 ViewController with 2 buttons and 2 labels to interact with the view and then 2 labels that show the result when the buttons are pressed.

Now when I use the method `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` and have set the content to import in the settings bundle I can only inject numbers, when I set letters in the settings app, they do not get injected. However when I inject it straight from the app there is no problem.

On the View Controller, I can retrieve both letters and numbers.

This would have me believe that the problem lies with the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method.

Now I am not sure where the bug lies with this, because using that injection method and setting the letters or text in the ViewController works fine.

I need the webView, but when pulling content from the settings bundle it will only show the numbers in the textField. If you watch the console though, you will see that the letters and numbers are being recognized.

I am happy to give any additional details if I have left anything out.
Please if someone would be so kind to download the project and have a look, to see if what I am trying to say makes any sense, I would greatly appreciate that.

it is written with the 5.1 SDK

Kind Regards,
Jeff

[Download Project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/61711378/Field_testing.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after pulling out all my hairs I have found the answer:

```
%@", field01];
```

I had the code above, but for some reason that only lets through numbers or maybe they are integers anyway, no letters are being let through, yet to a label they are.

so I compared a hardcoded string to a dynamic string that I require and noticed that they hard coded string had the value between ' & ' so I put the %@ between those and it fixed the problem.

so `'%@'", field01];` fixed it all:-)

Cheers